# generic javascript to handle radio button enable/disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the radio buttons to be enabled only when the associated checkbox is checked. So I need help in writing a generic javascript code, which will work for all the checkboxes. I have about 100 checkboxes, so I don't want to write each ID or name manually in the javascript code. Can a code sample be presented on how to do this in a generic way.

```
<form name=registration>
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='c1' name=selcourse value='2-PM-030' onChange="enabledSDF(1,this.value);"> Microsoft Project 2013 </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=radio id=cd name='2-PM-030' value='Dec 11-12'>Dec 11-12</td>
    <td><input type=radio id=c1d1 name='2-PM-030' value='Jan 26-27'>Jan 26-27</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' id='c2' name=selcourse value='2-PM-050'> Microsoft Project 2010 </td>
    <td><input type=radio id=c2d1 name='2-PM-050' value='Nov 24-25'>Nov 24-25</td>
    <td><input type=radio id=c2d2 name='2-PM-050' value='Dec 18-19'>Dec 18-19</td>
    <td><input type=radio id=c2d3 name='2-PM-050' value='Jan 29-30'>Jan 29-30</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I found the following  pieces of code, but I am not sure how to make it generic.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function()

function enabledSDF(i,value){
    var form = document.registration;
    if(document.getElementById('course_type').value=='C')
    {
            if (value=="Singaporean"){
                document.getElementById("sdf"+i+"0").disabled='';
                document.getElementById("sdf"+i+"1").disabled='';
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("sdf"+i+"0").disabled='disabled';
                document.getElementById("sdf"+i+"1").disabled='disabled';
            }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{

    $("#email_acc").click(function()
    { 
        if ( $(this).is(":checked") ) 
        {  
            $("input[name='radio_email']").removeAttr("disabled");

        }else {

            $("input[name='radio_email']").attr ( "disabled" , true );
        }
    });  

    $("#sys_acc").click(function()
    {
        if ( $(this).is(":checked") )
        {   
            $("input[name='radio_system']").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {

            $("input[name='radio_system']").attr ( "disabled" , true );
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .on('change', checkboxChange) // do it when you change the checkbox
    .each(checkboxChange); // as well as once when the page loads

  function checkboxChange() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    $('input[name="' + $checkbox.attr('value') + '"]').prop('disabled', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name=registration>
  <table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' id='c1' name=selcourse value='2-PM-030' onChange="enabledSDF(1,this.value);">Microsoft Project 2013</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <input type=radio id=cd name='2-PM-030' value='Dec 11-12'>Dec 11-12</td>
      <td>
        <input type=radio id=c1d1 name='2-PM-030' value='Jan 26-27'>Jan 26-27</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' id='c2' name=selcourse value='2-PM-050'>Microsoft Project 2010</td>
      <td>
        <input type=radio id=c2d1 name='2-PM-050' value='Nov 24-25'>Nov 24-25</td>
      <td>
        <input type=radio id=c2d2 name='2-PM-050' value='Dec 18-19'>Dec 18-19</td>
      <td>
        <input type=radio id=c2d3 name='2-PM-050' value='Jan 29-30'>Jan 29-30</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

### EDIT: If not linked by common attribute value

If the radio buttons don't have the same name as the value of the checkbox that is meant to disable them, then you would need to traverse from the checkbox that was changed to the `<tr>` that contains them, then find the radio buttons within that.

To do that, just change my `checkboxChange()` function as follows.

```
function checkboxChange() {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    $checkbox.closest('tr').find('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', !$checkbox.prop('checked'));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much GregL. Much appreciated. It is working beautifully. But I am unable to understand how the radio button is getting disbaled when the code only check for the checkbox field.

Comment: The relationship between the radio buttons and the checkboxes is that the checkboxes have a `value` attribute equal to the `name` attribute of the radio buttons. So my `checkboxChange()` function finds radio buttons with a `name` equal to the `value` of the checkbox in question, and disables them if that checkbox is _not_ checked.

Make sense now?

Comment: Thanks GregL. But what would you recommend if the radio button name was not the same as the value of the checkbox?

Comment: @vinai See the edit to my question. That's probably a better way of doing it, to be honest.

Comment: Thanks Greg. This worked perfectly. Two Thumbs Up to Your Quick Work.

Comment: separately, is it possible to alert a user if they try to click on this disabled radio button... and tell them to select the check box first. I feel that a disabled radio button may not trigger any code. How to capture this... any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Correct, a disabled radio button will not trigger any events. However, I did find that if you add the CSS rule `pointer-events: none;`, you can bind a click handler to a containing element and it will work correctly, see [this quick demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/z1pLpdcf/) I made. It worked for me in Chrome at least.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
  <form name=registration>
<table border=1>
<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class="des" data-year='2013' name=selcourse value='2-PM-030'> Microsoft Project 2013 </td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type=radio class="2013" name='2-PM-030' value='Dec 11-12'>Dec 11-12</td>
    <td><input type=radio class="2013" name='2-PM-030' value='Jan 26-27'>Jan 26-27</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type='checkbox' class="des" data-year='2010' name=selcourse value='2-PM-050'> Microsoft Project 2010 </td>
    <td><input type=radio class="2010" name='2-PM-050' value='Nov 24-25'>Nov 24-25</td>
    <td><input type=radio class="2010" name='2-PM-050' value='Dec 18-19'>Dec 18-19</td>
    <td><input type=radio class="2010" name='2-PM-050' value='Jan 29-30'>Jan 29-30</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$('.des').on('change', function () {
  var type = $(this).data('year');
  if(this.checked){
    $('.' + type).attr('disabled', 'true');
  } else {
    $('.' + type).removeAttr( "disabled" );
  }
});
```

if you already are using jquery, it's better if you take advantage of that

Comment: AFAIK, it is better to use `.prop('disabled', <boolean>)` instead of `.attr('disabled', 'true')`. The presence of the disabled attribute does not always correspond to the disabled property, which is what controls the disabled status of the checkbox.